# Merging multiple workbooks into single sheet in current workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I need VBA code to select multiple workbooks by browsing the files and then merge all those into 1 sheet of current workbook.

All multiple workbooks having only 1 sheet

headers is same for all workbooks so header is constant

Merging should not get any empty rows while filling workbook by workbook

No repetition of headers when merging.

When 1st workbook merging is done, 2nd workbook data should be merged in the same sheet of current workbook exactly next row of the merged 1st workbook data ends which means no empty rows or gaps

Comment: Please post the code you have so far and state any **specific** problems you have with it and please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Lucky for you, I have this for something at work so I can share the code. Couple questions first: 1) what row would you expect to never have any blanks? Need this to determine how far down to copy. 2) what columns will be copied? I’m guessing starting from A, but ending where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, This will not paste any headers. Since they are all the same, just move the headers to the excel that will store the consolidation. (No need for a macro to do this since it only needs to happen once).

Second, in the code you need to change "SHEETNAME?" to the name of the sheet on your main book that will store the consolidation. (2 instances, do not remove quotes)

Third, I am assuming there is no blanks in Column A which is what determines how far down to copy. If you expect blanks in Column A, this needs to be amended to reflect a column that is least likely to have blanks.

Lastly, I am copying from Column A to Z. Change the "Z" to the last column in your file that contains data.

Given the quality of (or lack of) your question, this is more than you bargained for :)
Happy Editing.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Consolidation()

Dim CurrentBook As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEETNAME?")
Dim IndvFiles As FileDialog
Dim FileIdx As Long
Dim i As Integer, x As Integer

Set IndvFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With IndvFiles
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Multi-select target data files:"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add ".xlsx files", "*.xlsx"
    .Show
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For FileIdx = 1 To IndvFiles.SelectedItems.Count
    Set CurrentBook = Workbooks.Open(IndvFiles.SelectedItems(FileIdx))
    For Each Sheet In CurrentBook.Sheets
        Dim LRow1 As Long
        LRow1 = WS.Range("A" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim LRow2 As Long
        LRow2 = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim ImportRange As Range
        Set ImportRange = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:Z" & LRow2)
        ImportRange.Copy
        WS.Range("A" & LRow1 + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Next
    CurrentBook.Close False
Next FileIdx

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: few variables here not defined.. So I defined WB as workbook and WS as worksheet.. but still Im getting 1 error at the line                                                                                                                           LRow1 = WB.Sheets("SHEETNAME?").Range("A" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row..                                                   here my sheet name is sheet1 which I changed already, but WB unable to refer which sheet should be consider I guess

Comment: LRow2 = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2" & CurrentBook.ActivateSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row                                                                                                              im getting error in this line.... Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: after swapping with CurrentBook.Sheet.. no change in the error

Comment: same thing error on same line... no change.. Have you tried this code from your side ?

Comment: it worked for you??? could you pls replace the above code with your working code ..so that I can try with that working code.

Comment: I found the error in this line LRow2 = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2" & CurrentBook.ActivateSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 its not activatesheet its active sheet. thanks a lot . code is working absolutely fine :)

Comment: just a suggestion, it would be advisable to add `Application.CutCopyMode = False` at the end of the macro to ensure that Excel isn't taking up too much of the clipboard

Answer (score 0):

How about this option?  Modify to suit your needs.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm