# my code merging all workbooks into seperate sheets. i need to merge all in 1 same sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to merge the workbooks by browsing and selecting multiple workbooks time and getting all data in current workbook. I need all data of selected workbooks in 1 sheet.But my code gives in different sheets of current workbook.                 **sheets.Copy after:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)**       as per this line,syntax allowing me to opt either after or before but not giving current. pls help me out

```
Dim files, i As Integer
Dim dailogbox As FileDialog
Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
Dim sheets As Worksheet

Set mainWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set dailogbox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

dailogbox.AllowMultiSelect = True

files = dailogbox.Show

For i = 1 To dailogbox.SelectedItems.Count
    Workbooks.Open dailogbox.SelectedItems(i)
    Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each sheets In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
        sheets.Copy after:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

    Next tempWorkSheet

    sourceWorkbook.Close
Next i
```

Comment: didn't [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477715/merging-multiple-workbooks-into-single-sheet-in-current-workbook) work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, **Sheets.Copy** will copy or move the entire sheet. It will not merge the data into another sheet. You will have to copy the cells of the sheet you want to copy,

```
dim dest as Range
For i = 1 To dailogbox.SelectedItems.Count
    Workbooks.Open dailogbox.SelectedItems(i)
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(dailogbox.SelectedItems(i))

    For Each aSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets '
        set dest = mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)        
        aSheet.Cells.Copy dest.Cells
    Next sheets   ' NOT "tempWorkSheet"

    sourceWorkbook.Close
Next i
```

Also: "Sheets" is a reserved word. You can't use it as a variable. I changed it to "aSheet".

EDIT: To copy the formatting after copying the text, add this after `aSheet.Cells.Copy dest.Cells`:

```
dest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: `sheets.Cells.Copy dest` will fail if `dest` is anything less than a whole sheet.  You need to limit the copy to the used range only.  Also, avoid the `ActiveWorkbook` by using `Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(dailogbox.SelectedItems(i))`

Comment: @chrisneilsen, is this better now?

Comment: Better, but worth noting that `.UsedRange` has potential issues (note: I said used range, not `.UsedRange` </End Pedantry>) There are other reliable ways of obtaining the used range.  That said, there are lots on answers on SO that deal with that, so lets not sidetrack _this_ Q on side issues

Comment: set dest = .......... i want the whole sheet to get copied.. i cant keep range when range of sheets are not constant in this case. this is where im struck.. and usedrange is getting copied to dest which sounds good . but let me know what if entire sheet want to copy to dest

Comment: aSheet.UsedRange.Copy dest this line works well for data when you have data from A1.. but what if some columns are not filled, Some starts with c column that too data having blanks somewhere.. which is not giving the exact result ..something wrong with the used range

Comment: @harshakazama  aSheet.Cells.Copy will copy all the cells on the sheet. Changing my answer above.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I guess my response to your initial comment was backwards. Instead of changing `sheets.cells.copy` I should have redefined `dest` as the whole sheet!  I didn't know that's what @harshakazama had in mind all along!

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson thank you sir.. its working... I would be more happy if you can help me in adding bit code to copy data along with the all formats from source sheet..

Answer (score 0):

This will open a file dialog allowing you to select multiple files, it will then cycle through each sheet on the work books, copy the data from A2 to the bottom right corner of your data, and paste it in the workbook that hosts this code.

Things you will need to modify or amend for:
1) The sheet name of your book that hosts this code
2) The Col span (A-Z right now)
3) If your import books have multiple sheets, you need to set a criteria for which sheets you want to import since this will grab every sheet from every selected workbook.
4) This assumes Col A does not have any blanks (to determine last row (what range to copy) you need to pick a column that is least likely to have blanks so you dont miss data.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Consolidation()

Dim CurrentBook As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEETNAME?")
Dim IndvFiles As FileDialog
Dim FileIdx As Long
Dim i As Integer, x As Integer

Set IndvFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With IndvFiles
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Multi-select target data files:"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add ".xlsx files", "*.xlsx"
    .Show
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For FileIdx = 1 To IndvFiles.SelectedItems.Count
    Set CurrentBook = Workbooks.Open(IndvFiles.SelectedItems(FileIdx))
    For Each Sheet In CurrentBook.Sheets
        Dim LRow1 As Long
        LRow1 = WS.Range("A" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim LRow2 As Long
        LRow2 = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim ImportRange As Range
        Set ImportRange = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:Z" & LRow2)
        ImportRange.Copy
        WS.Range("A" & LRow1 + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Next
    CurrentBook.Close False
Next FileIdx

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're after this (explanations in comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheets()
    Dim files As Variant, i As Long
    Dim dailogbox As FileDialog
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet, targetSheet As Worksheet

    Set targetSheet = ActiveSheet ' set the sheet you want to collect selecte workbooks worksheets data into

    Set dailogbox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    dailogbox.AllowMultiSelect = True

    files = dailogbox.Show

    For i = 1 To dailogbox.SelectedItems.Count
        With Workbooks.Open(dailogbox.SelectedItems(i)) ' open and reference current workbook
            For Each mySheet In .Worksheets ' loop through current workbook worksheets
                mySheet.UsedRange.Copy targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' copy current worksheet "used" range and paste them into target sheet from its column A first empty cell after last not empty one
            Next
            .Close False ' cloe current workbook, discarding changes
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```